# Add Favourites to create a list then email list as part of an enquiry form

Tags: wordpress

I have a client that wants a property directory, but they want users to be able to favourite multiple properties - then view their favourite properties on separate page - then send all those properties to a single email address as part of an enquiry.

cannot see how to do this using agentpress framework

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, the first is to save as properties in session. The second if users are logged in to Wordpress is to use admin-ajax to add the properties as a meta data of the user. So this way you can access these meta infos using get_user_meta();

Documentation:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Comment: thank you. i think it needs to be users don't have to login. i cant even find a plugin for this!